# A ClassNotFoundException error occurred in loading the message receiver org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am trying to run a SOAP Web Services based application and I am not quite sure what this error is about. 
Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
try {
    URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://localhost:8081/JAXWS-Tomcat/userWS?wsdl");
    QName qname = new QName("http://service.jaxws.journaldev.com/", "UserServiceImpl");
    Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, qname);
    UserService us = service.getPort(UserService.class);

    MyPackage myPackage =  new MyPackage();



} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The full error description:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error getting Client Configuration Context : A ClassNotFoundException error occurred in loading the message receiver org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:118)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getClientConfigurationContext(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:78)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:218)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:83)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:79)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:36)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:116)
at start.SOAPClient.main(SOAPClient.java:17)
```

The exception is thrown at Service.create() method call.

And here is my pom.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ds</groupId>
    <artifactId>ass4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-jaxws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.3.1</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>corp1</id>
            <name>Corporate Repository</name>
            <url>scp://repo/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

I have tried all I can think of, considering I'm new at this SOAP web services area, so I could really use some help. 
Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I had to pay more attention to pom.xml and add javax mail and (I belive) amqp-client jars to tomcat lib. Also, disable avast antivirus. I hope I don't remember it wrong.

Comment: Am having the same problem now, and Avast is not even installed.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by adding the correct dependency to my pom.xml:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-adb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```